Initially display image and hide it from shiny modularized app using an actionButton
Below I create a shiny app with modules. The app is simple initially an image is displayed and when the actionButton is clicked the image is hidden. Now I get this in the beginning. The png is stored as app.png

app.R
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinydashboard)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(dplyr)

source("sideUI.R")
source("sideServer.R")
source("imgUI.R")
source("imgServer.R")

# Build ui & server and then run
ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Biodiversity"),
  dashboardSidebar(sideUI("side")),
  dashboardBody(
    useShinyjs(),
    imgUI("imgPL")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  # Use the reactive in another module
  city_input <- sideServer("side")
  imgServer("imgPL", btn = city_input$btn)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

imgUI.R
imgUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tagList(
    div(
      id = ns("showimg"),
      img(src='C:/Users/User/Documents/appsilon2/appsilon-main/www/apps.png', align = "center")
    )
  )
}

imgServer.R
imgServer <- function(id, btn) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      ns <- session$ns  # Create the namespace function
      observeEvent(btn(), {
        shinyjs::hide(id = ns("showimg"))  # Use namespaced ID
      })
    }
  )
}

sideUI.R
sideUI <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  tagList(
    actionButton(ns("action"), "Submit")
  )
}

sideServer.R
sideServer <- function(id) {
  moduleServer(
    id,
    function(input, output, session) {
      return(btn = reactive(input$action))
    }
  )
}


Image files should be stored in a subfolder named www and not in the main app folder. That is likely why your image file is not being read into the app.

i did that but stii mot displayed

Try img(src='apps.png', align = "center") instead of img(src='C:/Users/User/Documents/appsilon2/appsilon-main/www/apps.png', align = "center") when the image file is in www folder.

It looks like your questions has been answered and now you have a new question about aligning images in Shiny apps.  This has nothing to do with action buttons, and very little to do with modules.  If you can't find a similar question, please write a very minimal shiny app with only the image and post that.

I guess you want img(src = 'apps.png', style = "align: center"). align is a css property not an HTML attribute.

the image remains after hitting the actionbutton while it should not
